# Bookmarklet and CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I need to write bookmarklet code using CoffeScript. Something like this (JS):

```
javascript: (function () {  
//....
}());
```

But when I'm trying to write this code in CoffeeScript

```
javascript: (->
#...
)()
```

I got following:

```
({
  javascript: (function() {
//...
  })()
});
```

How to avoid adding of "({ });"

Answer (score 1):

You can add `-b` (or `--bare` flag) to compile without a top-level function wrapper.
See more at the `$ coffee --help`.

**Upd**
`-b` is of no help if you want to get rid of braces and around `javascript: ..` -- they are part of javascript object syntax.

You can write your coffee code without `javascript:` (which in the case of bookmarklet is a protocol name, not part of the code), but add it later:

```
$ echo '(-> alert "hello!")()' > xx.coffee
$ echo javascript:`coffee -bjcp xx.coffee`
javascript:(function() { return alert("hello!"); })();
```

Comment: I always compile coffee files with following flags: -wbco But I got this wrapper anyway

Comment: Oh, sorry. Seems I just misread your question. See updated answer.